# Formula that depends on input from another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to write a formula where it subtracts the value of F from the previous F where G is true. Is it possible to have the cell know which cell is the previous true? for  instance I want the formula in H4 to subtract F4 from F3, but once it gets to cell H7 it should subtract F7 from F4 since neither G5-G6 are TRUE. Is this possible at all, or is there a better approach to this??

[image: Picture is a photo of the dataset in question]

Comment: Use `XLOOKUP` searching for TRUE, and returning the odometer column. Search mode should be -1, and anchor the first half of your lookup and return array. I leave the rest up to you as it's unclear what the whole formula would be when the row doesn't have true

Comment: That is such a good idea! thanks so much. rows without true I am assuming the data is unreliable so I will be ignoring it.

Comment: Another option is to create a new hidden column, say it becomes H., give it a formula if Gx is TRUE, return Fx, otherwise return Hx-1, then reference to Hx. x is the current rownumber. Also, give H1 the value you want to return in case the G2 = not true. Eg 0.